# How to simplify these indexes to increase performance of SQL queries

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm using the following fields in WHERE clauses of different SQL queries in the given order. Should I create index on individual columns, or should I create compound indexes. How can I simplify the following to create less indexes that perform better.

members table

```
member_id (primary key)
WHERE user_id = $user_id AND member_id = $member_id
WHERE user_id = $user_id AND name LIKE '%$keywords%'
WHERE user_id = $user_id AND expiry_date < CURDATE()
WHERE user_id = $user_id AND expiry_date BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '2000-01-01'
```

payments table

```
payment_id (primary key)
WHERE user_id = $user_id AND member_id = $member_id
WHERE user_id = $user_id AND member_id = $member_id AND payment_id = $payment_id
```

"users" table is not mentioned here, which is actually the main accounts table that has many members in members table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your tables are InnoDB:

> `WHERE user_id = $user_id AND expiry_date < CURDATE()`

Create an index on `(user_id, expiry_date)`

> `WHERE user_id = $user_id AND name LIKE '%$keywords%'`

This won't benefit from an index, as the like condition you're using is not sargable. You can create a covering index on `(user_id, name)` though.

> `WHERE user_id = $user_id AND member_id = $member_id`

No index needed as `member_id` is a primary key

> `WHERE user_id = $user_id AND member_id = $member_id AND payment_id = $payment_id`

No index needed as `payment_id` is a primary key.

Comment: So, where no index is needed, do I have to change the order of usage, I mean for example bring the payment_id to the most left

Comment: @user3651934 no you don't, MySQL optimizer will handle the order itself. I personally usually place the predicates in the index order, but that's just for legibility, it does not affect the optimizer's decisions in any way.

Comment: For more discussion, see my [cookbook on creating an index from a SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).